# Can't install Ubuntu using HDMI

Tags: installation, hdmi

I have a Dell Inspiron 660s with an HDMI monitor. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and after I choose "Install Ubuntu" from the boot menu, the screen shuts off and I can't see anything. How do I get the Ubuntu installer to work with an HDMI monitor?

Comment: Posted by [apfelsine](http://askubuntu.com/users/94782/apfelsine) as an answer: *"are you using an intel integrated graphics or some PCIe videocard?"*

Comment: It's the onboard video, so I'm assuming Intel integrated graphics.

Comment: Can you try the `nomodeset` option as described in [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) Also, you tagged the question with `wubi`, but the body of your post seems to indicate you're not running Wubi. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just using the Mythbuntu installer, which seems to use a slightly different image and boot settings and works fine with HDMI. By default, it only installs a stripped down XFCE desktop, but installing the ubuntu-desktop and gnome-shell packages installs the normal Unity/Gnome desktop.